# Is there a way to use scanner to read in a full string including the spaces, without reading the full line?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, delimiter

Let's say my text file looks like this:

```
John Doe    18    male
Amy hun     19    female
```

I need to read this into an array like so

```
while(reader.hasNextLine()){

    result[i] = new Person(reader.next(),reader.next(),reader.next());
    reader.nextLine();
    i++;
}
```

but it keeps messing up my array because it treats each space as a delimiter and does not use it, where the columns are separated by whitespace.

I tried using delimiter to spaces on my scanner but I get the error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException. Tried a few things but no luck too. I also can't just read in both names as separate Strings because some rows will only have one name.

Comment: You need to parse the line, and regular expressions can help you to do this.

Comment: e.g. `String line = reader.nextLine();` so line may hold `"John Doe    18    male"`, and then `String[] tokens = lineOfText.split("(?<=\\d)\\s+|\\s+(?=\\d)");` where tokens holds: `{"John Doe", "18", "male"}`

Comment: Where the regular expression, `"(?<=\\d)\\s+|\\s+(?=\\d)"` splits at a number followed by white-space: `"(?<=\\d)\\s+` or white-space followed by a number: `\\s+(?=\\d)"`

Comment: Yeah, thanks. This pointed me towards the right direction. I used:  String[] array = words.split("\\t");

Answer (score 0):

You will want to read each line of text, and then parse the line using regex or "regular expressions". The regex is a flexible way of grabbing parts of Strings that match certain rules. For instance, if you iterate through the file line by line, grabbing each line with `reader.nextLine()`:

```
while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = reader.nextLine();
    // ...
}
```

now `line` holds an line from the file, such as `"John Doe    18    male"`

Then you will want to split this line into 3 substrings representing the name, age, and sex, and they are represented by text followed by a number followed by text, all split by white space (spaces)

If you call `.split(...)` on the String, you can use a regex that will divide the String based on these rules:

```
String regex = "(?<=\\d)\\s+|\\s+(?=\\d)";
```

This works because the regular expression, `"(?<=\\d)\\s+|\\s+(?=\\d)"` splits at a number followed by white-space: `(?<=\\d)\\s+` or white-space followed by a number: `\\s+(?=\\d)` using regex look-ahead and look-behind rules.

This will split the string into the tokens: `{"John Doe", "18", "male"}`

The whole thing could look like:

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();

String regex = "(?<=\\d)\\s+|\\s+(?=\\d)";

while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = reader.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = line.split(regex);
    Person person = new Person(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2]);
    // or perhaps:
    // Person person = new Person(tokens[0], Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]), tokens[2]);
    personList.add(person);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your Scanner's delimiter appropriately:

```
reader.useDelimiter("(?<=\\d)\\s+|\\s+(?=\\d)|\n");
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/A782bp).

This sets the delimiter to:

- "some spaces after a digit", or
- "some spaces before a digit", or
- "a newline"

With this, you can use your code as-is (see test code below).

---

Some test code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input ="John Doe    18    male\nAmy hun     19    female\n";
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("(?<=\\d)\\s+|\\s+(?=\\d)|\n");
    Person[] result = new Person[10];
    int i = 0;
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        result[i++] = new Person(reader.next(), reader.next(), reader.next());
    }
    Arrays.stream(result).filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(System.out::println);
}

static class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final String age;
    private final String gender;

    Person(String name, String age, String gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age='" + age + '\'' +
                ", gender='" + gender + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Person{name='John Doe', age='18', gender='male'}
Person{name='Amy hun', age='19', gender='female'}
```